# What methods/events are invoked when a DLL is referenced in another project

Tags: c#

I have a C# based application where I am consuming an external DLL. The external DLL has a simple method 
called IsEven() ,which takes a number as input and tell us whether the no is even or odd. Now I am consuming the DLL by adding it as a reference in my project. I wanted to know even before I call the method "IsEven()" on the DLL  , is there any other predefined that will be called on the DLL ? I actually want to perform some action before any method on the DLL is called.

Comment: Is the DLL written in C#, or something like C/C++?

Comment: Yes the external DLL is written in C#

Comment: No, there is no "module loaded" event in .NET: [There's a proposal for module initializers](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2608)

Comment: Seems like a static constructor on whatever class is implementing `IsEven` should probably be able to do whatever is required. The timings aren't quite the same as if you were able to have a [DllMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain).

Comment: Note that you *do* need a static constructor for this to work: just having a static field initializer won't (this is to do with [`beforefieldinit`](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/beforefieldinit.html))

Comment: Thanks mates. I think this gives me a right direction to go towards.